# How to check booked slots with dates given

Tags: php, laravel

This is my array and I want to return Array who has already booked date-wise.
Currently it is working time-wise, but when I do this for more than one day it stops working:

```php
$bookedData  = array(   
    Id : 1
    date : "2020-03-31"
    endDate : "2020-04-01"
    time : "19:00:00"
    endTime : "11:30:00"
)
foreach($bookedData as $booked) {             /* checking fr all slots*/
    if (strlen($booked->time) > 0 && strlen($booked->endTime) > 0 {
        if ($booked->time !=$booked->endTime) {
            $appStrtTime = strtotime($booked->time); /* It gives time startTime */
            $appEndTime = strtotime($booked->endtime); /* It gives endTime */

            $AddMins = 5*60;
            while ($appStartTime < $appEndTime) {  /* if starttime is less than endtime then return false */
                $time = date("G:i:s", $appStartTime);
                $key = array_search($time, $ReturnArray);
                if($key!= false) {
                    unset($ReturnArray[$key]); /* if slot already available then unset it */
                }
                $appStartTime +=$AddMins;
            }
            $appStartTime += $AddMins;
        }
    } else {
        $key = array_search($booked->time, $ReturnArray);
        if ($key != false) {
                unset($ReturnArray[$key]);
        }
    }
    }
}
if (count($ReturnArray) > 0) {
    unset($ReturnArray[count($ReturnArray) - 1]);
}
$ReturnArray = array_values($ReturnArray);  
}
```

Comment: How are you getting this array $bookedData. Is it hard coded or is there any query for it. If there is a query there before looping you can handle it in the query only.

Comment: This booked data is coming from query.So how do you recommend to do this thing? I tried but not getting result

Comment: This PHP code isn't valid. `date(format: "G:i:s", $appStartTime);`

Comment: i updated my code, sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment

> For example if i select starttime date as 31 march and time as 19:00 then i want to get all the slots after that time like 19:00,19:15,... Upto end date

I would go for this code here:

```
$start = new \DateTime('2020-03-31 19:00');
$end = new \DateTime('2020-03-31 21:30');
$slotSize = 15; // 15 minute intervals

$slots = [];
do {
    // Add here your custom code to skip specific timeslots
    // As an example I used a custom function as an example
    if (slot_is_blocked_by_existing_bookings($slot, $bookings)) {
        continue;
    }

    $slots[] = clone $start;
} while ($start->add(new \DateInterval("PT{$slotSize}M")) <= $end);
```

and here is an example output of the `$slots`-list which contains DateTime-objets (string formatted to RFC3339 for readability reasons)

```
array:11 [
  0 => "2020-03-31T19:00:00+00:00"
  1 => "2020-03-31T19:15:00+00:00"
  2 => "2020-03-31T19:30:00+00:00"
  3 => "2020-03-31T19:45:00+00:00"
  4 => "2020-03-31T20:00:00+00:00"
  5 => "2020-03-31T20:15:00+00:00"
  6 => "2020-03-31T20:30:00+00:00"
  7 => "2020-03-31T20:45:00+00:00"
  8 => "2020-03-31T21:00:00+00:00"
  9 => "2020-03-31T21:15:00+00:00"
  10 => "2020-03-31T21:30:00+00:00"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some edits of your code:

```
$appStartTime = strtotime($booked['date'] . ' ' . $booked['time']);
$appEndTime = strtotime($booked['endDate'] . ' ' . $booked['endTime']);
```

```
while ($appStartTime < $appEndTime) 
{

   $time = strtotime($appStartTime);
   // ...carry on with the rest of the code

}
```

Comment: I had tried this ,but i am only getting the start time slot not getting all the slots after that time. My main goal is to remove all the slots after that start time in return array.For example if i select starttime date as 31 march and time as 19:00 then i want to get all the slots after that time like 19:00,19:15,... Upto end date